# Giving JW Player a movie file from a database

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, mp4, jwplayer

What im trying to do is play a .mp4 file in JW Player that is given by a database in bytes.

So here is my Script for JW Player:

```css
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jwplayer("contvideo").setup({ 
    flashplayer:"jwplayer/player.swf", 
    file: "downloadvideo.aspx", 
    provider: "video", 
    height: 140, 
    width: 188, 
    skin: "jwplayer/slim.zip", 
    modes: [{type:'flash',src:'jwplayer/player.swf'},{type:'html5'},{type:'download'}] }); 
</script>
```

The script recives its movie file from the web page service downloadvideo.aspx.

The code for downloadvideo.aspx is:

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim bytes() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\websites\videospecialty\wdo.mp4")

    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=wdo.mp4")
    Response.ContentType = "video/mp4"
    Response.Flush()

    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    Response.OutputStream.Flush()

    Response.End()

End Sub
```

But when i try this JW Player errors and says that they video was not found.

Any help with this would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that JW Player figures out the kind of file to play based on the file extension in the `file` option. Because you are streaming these from disk, via an ASPX page, you don't have one.

The following is how I got this working with JW Player 6 (using mp3s - I didn't have any mp4s handy):

```
jwplayer("player1").setup({
    flashplayer: "/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
    file: '/Streamer.ashx',
    height: 340,
    width: 388,
    type: 'mp3'
});
```

The key was the use of `type` to indicate what kind of file was on the other end. The only reference I can offer for this is [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/74/php-http-streaming): it dates back to 2007, but I couldn't seem to find mentions of `type` in the documention.

Inspired by:
[How do I stream .flv files from SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399728/how-do-i-stream-flv-files-from-sql-database), I implemeted an HTTP handler to do the streaming:

```
public class Streamer : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string filePath = "my file path";
        byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg3");
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=file.mp3");
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());

        context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that an ASPX page would probably work fine as well, though handlers are more appropriate for this kind of task (and should be more efficient as they don't have a page cycle).

Reading the whole file into memory isn't ideal, but it sufficed for proving the concept.